# pandas DataFrame transpose/melt/pivot for one column only

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this in a pandas DataFrame:

[image: Data 1]

And I would like to transform it to this (in a pandas DataFrame):

[image: Data result]

I tried to use df.melt(), df.pivot(), and df.T() but it didn't work out for me since they transformed all the columns... Anyone knows how to fix this (using something else than pd Dataframe is also fine, I have my data in a csv file)?

Comment: It's better if you post text and not images of text.

Comment: Thanks John Zwinck, you are right, I will take that into account next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (df)
  name group  weight
0    a     e      60
1    t     g      70
2    p     d      80
3    f     d      40
4    e     e      50
5    l     g      30
6    a     d      20

print (df.pivot(index='name', columns='group', values='weight').fillna(''))
group   d   e   g
name             
a      20  60    
e          50    
f      40        
l              30
p      80        
t              70
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this worked for me! :)  I used df.pivot_table() instead of df.pivot(), since df.pivot() gave me a duplicated entries error.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out that some of the names do not occur after I used df.pivot(). So I lost some data. Jezrael do you know how this is caused?

Comment: Interesting, can you add sample?

Comment: Yes :)  I first opened the csf file with a length of 3375 names (which are 422 unique names). Then I used df.pivot and then I should have a table with 422 rows, but instead it has 413.. Is there an easy way how I can know which names are missing?

Comment: Is possible share your data if not confidental?

Comment: Yes that is possible :) How do I do I share my data?

Comment: by dropbox, google docs, or wetransfer. You have to post link to comment.

Comment: The first link is all the data and the second link is the data that I pivoted

Comment: Ok, please give me time.

Comment: Okay thanks! I continue looking at it :) I really appreciate your willingness to help

Comment: I found out that the Baked Whole Pumpkin recipe occurs two times on the website where I scraped the information from. So there are recipes with the same name, but a different recipe_id

Comment: Jezrael I figured it out. It was a stupid thing with recipes with the same names... I looked at this the entire morning and when I ask help I suddenly see it.. :( I am sorry! But thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, sometimes other eyes are better, if man is in ends. I am glad that it works for you. Nice day. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one line:

```
df.set_index(['name','group']).unstack()
```